# Camera service recording

Tags: android, android-service, android-camera2

I'm currently recording videos using the camera2 api in a service.

I can't find a way to update the output list of a camerasession when the previewing surface is destroyed. In other words: what to do when one surface is destroyed ( when activity goes in background for example ) to keep recording and avoid crashes due to null surface.

This is how I start the recording of the video.

```
private void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        closePreviewSession();
        setUpMediaRecorder();

        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();
        if(mTextureView !=null) {
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());            // Set up Surface for the camera preview
            previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
        }

        // Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
        Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

        // Start a capture session
        // Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Timber.e("Error when creating captureSession");
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I send the activity to the background: the previewing surface is destroyed, and this is where I struggle. How should I update my capturesession in order to remove the previewing surface from the session output without stopping the capture in progress ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never want to have the preview working again, you can simply create a new preview request, and not add the the previewSurface into it, once the TextureView is gone.

If you want to connect up a preview later without interruption, that's more complicated.  One option is to start with your own SurfaceTexture, and use its attachToGlContext/detachFromGlContext calls along with a GLSurfaceView or similar.

Then you can configure a session with the SurfaceTexture, and whenever you want to show preview, attach it to a GLSurfaceView's GL context and add the Surface to your preview request targets.  Then when you want to stop showing preview, remove the Surface from the preview targets, and detach it from the GLSurfaceView.

That requires having your own GL drawing code (basically your own mini TextureView with custom behavior), so it's a lot of boilerplate, but it's simple EGL (just need to draw a quadrilateral with the preview texture on it).